# Example of hypergraph

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

**Definition:** A *hypergraph* $\Gamma=(V,\mathcal{E})$ is a set of vertices $V$ and a collection $\mathcal{E}$ of subsets of $V$ such that for every $E\in \mathcal{E}$, we have $|E|\geq 2$. The members of $\mathcal{E}$ are called hypergraphs.

Example: Let $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and consider the collection $\mathcal{E}=\{\{1,2,4\}, \{3,4\}, \{2,3,4\}\}$.

However, I have tried to depict it. For instance, $\{1,2,4\}$ means that I've connected 1 and 2, 2 and 4, 1 and 4. I've the following picture.

Is it correct?

[image]

Comment: The idea behind a hypergraph is to generalize the notion of an edge to an object that connects more than two vertices, so a more accurate representation of it would be to fill in the triangle between edges $\{1,2,4\}$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, i guess in this case we should encircle each hyperedge with some set, right?

Answer (score 4):

The two main philosophies of hypergraph drawing are:

1. **The Set-Circling School** (shown on the left). Here, you just take every hyperedge and circle all the vertices involved with a continuous region.

   - Pros: Each edge is definitely unambiguously drawn.
   - Cons: Way more going on in the diagram, especially when lots of edges overlap.
2. **The Curved-Line School** (shown on the right). Here, you draw a curved line through all the vertices on a hyperedge, in arbitrary order, often sticking out a bit past the ends.

   - Pros: Minimalist. A natural generalization of graph drawings.
   - Cons: Not always obvious that it's the same edge entering and exiting a vertex.

[image: poorly drawn hypergraphs]

*(Note: in both of these examples, I misread the question and so both of these are drawings of the hypergraph with edge set $\{\{1,2,4\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{2,4\}\}$. Sorry. These drawings took a great deal of effort to make, so I'm not going to draw them all over again.)*

In both cases, the problem we are trying to solve is to make a drawing with the single hyperedge $\{1,2,4\}$ look different from from a drawing including some of the hyperedges $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,4\}$, $\{2,4\}$.

Comment: Thanks for post! I've realized that the main property of drawing of hypergraph is to realize from drawing what are it's hyper-edges, right?

Comment: @RFZ Yep, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

A way to see hypergraphs consists of representing its vertices and then enclosing the vertices belonging to a hyperedge into a set.

Comment: But what's worng with my picture? And why the way which you've pointed is much better?

Comment: In your representation, you also consider $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as hyperedge. The representation I'm suggesting identifies uniquely the whole hyperdege set.

Comment: Why? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: The real problem of your picture is that it does not describe in a unique way the hypergraph you're taking. For instance, consider the hypergraph on the same vertex set and take as hyperedges those you are considering and also the subsets $\{2,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$. How can you represent it? And moreover, when you take $\{1,2,3,4\}$, why cannot you link $1$ and $3$, $3$ and $4$ and finally $4$ and $2$. In this case, the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: I did not comprehend the essence of your last comment. Are there any flaws when we depict hypergraph as I did above?